# AWS: How to Create a DNS that point to private IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

i am new to using EC2, I have an EC2 instance that can reboot daily for maintenance and after the reboot, i get new public IP(i can't use elastic IPS there are all allocated).

so my problem is the instance contains an application that I need to be accessible via a domain (exemple.com), but I can figure out how to set custom DNS on NameCheap and in AWS this DNS automatically resolve the new public IP of that instance after reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you feel your architecture warrants additional Elastic IP addresses, you can request a limit increase. To request an increase, complete the [Amazon VPC](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc) limit request form (choose **VPC Elastic IP Address Limit**). Describe your use case so that AWS can understand your needs.
2. You can put your instance behind [ElasticLoadBalancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). Each Classic Load Balancer receives a default Domain Name System (DNS) name. This DNS name includes the name of the AWS region in which the load balancer is created. For example, if you create a load balancer named `my-loadbalancer` in the US West (Oregon) region, your load balancer receives a DNS name such as `my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. You can then use your DNS service to create a CNAME record to route queries to your load balancer. Then, your EC2 instance does not need to have stable public IP address.
3. You can delegate example.com resolution to AWS DNS service, [Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/), and then you can [run a script on server boot to update Route53 records](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20update%20Route53%20records%20after%20EC2%20instance%20restart) with the latest IP address.

Comment: #3 is good: It will update the DNS record to point to the new Public IP address.